# apt-get upgrade failure on libglib2.0-bin

Tags: apt, upgrade

im having problem updating my ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit)

ran below command

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

resulted to:

```
Setting up libglib2.0-bin (2.32.4-0ubuntu1) ...
rmdir: failed to remove `/etc/etc/': Not a directory
dpkg: error processing libglib2.0-bin (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lightdm:
lightdm depends on libglib2.0-bin; however:
Package libglib2.0-bin is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing lightdm (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity:
unity depends on libglib2.0-bin; however:
Package libglib2.0-bin is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing unity (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.                                                                      No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libglib2.0-bin
 lightdm
 unity
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libglib2.0-bin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-bin
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Note from comments: there appears to be a bug as described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1304557) There shouldn't be an `/etc/etc/` folder path.  I don't know how you got it. Try to reinstall dpkg with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg` if that fails try `sudo apt-get remove --purge dpkg` and install it again with `sudo apt-get install dpkg`.

Comment: when i run apt-get install libglib2.0-bin, resulted to below error : 

Setting up libglib2.0-bin (2.32.4-0ubuntu1) ...
rmdir: failed to remove `/etc/etc/': Not a directory
dpkg: error processing libglib2.0-bin (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libglib2.0-bin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: there appears to be a bug as described [here](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=Z241Vf23K8LANP2RgegP&gws_rd=cr&fg=1#safe=active&q=rmdir:+failed+to+remove+%2Fetc%2Fetc%2F) there shouldn't be `/etc/etc/` folder path I don't know how did you get it at the first place. Try to reinstall `dpkg` with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg` if not succeed try `sudo apt-get remove --purge dpkg` and install it back.